# Android animation: objects keep animating

Tags: android, animation

I'm writing an app where there are two buttons (card1, card2) who are animating (blink once). Card1, card2 are global variables and there values change each time. The code looks like this:

```
private void check(){
    card1.startAnimation(animFO1);
    card2.startAnimation(animFO2);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if(animation ==animFO1){
            card1=null;
            card2=null;
    }
}
```

What I want is that each time only these two buttons blink. But what happens is that once a button has blinked it blinks each time any button is animated... So if the program first select the two first buttons to be card1, card2 they both blink, if the program than selects the third and fourth button to be card1,card2 all four buttons blink...

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to use next code:

```
card1.clearAnimation();
card1.setAnimation(null);
```

Comment: The first rule gives an error but only writing the second one worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a method like this

```
card1.clearAnimation();
```